# Creating Custom UIView and display as Pop Up in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I am trying to create a custom `UIView` and display it as a pop up in my main View using Swift.

My Custom `UIView` code is

```
class DatePopUpView: UIView {
var uiView:UIView?

override init()  {
    super.init()
    self.uiView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("DatePopUpView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      }

required override init(frame: CGRect) {
           super.init(frame: frame)

}

}
```

And I am Calling it in my main view as:

```
 @IBAction func date_button_pressed (sender : AnyObject?) {
 var popUpView = DatePopUpView()
 var centre : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y)

    popUpView.center = centre
    popUpView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
  let trans = CGAffineTransformScale(popUpView.transform, 0.01, 0.01)
    popUpView.transform = trans
    self.view .addSubview(popUpView)
    UIView .animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options:     UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

        popUpView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(popUpView.transform, 100.0, 100.0)

        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in

    })

 }
```

But popUp is not Coming. I used breakpoint and noticed that value is getting assigned to my popUpView but still it is not displayed on my main View. Please Help

Please Note: I am using StoryBoard for my mainView and custom View i have made using xib.[image]

Comment: Are you sure your date_button_pressed() function is being called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73556/discussion-between-1s-and-0s-and-shruti).

Comment: OK, now I suspect your view.

Comment: Why don't you create a separate project temporarily. In the main vc load your nib and see if you can see and size your view. If it looks good then we can revisit this situations

Comment: I tried Giving the frame and adding `var popUpView = DatePopUpView() 
popUpView.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 200, 200) 
self.view .addSubview(popUpView)`
but no success

Comment: When I get into situations like this sometimes I create an empty project and copy only a file or two into it or cut and paste code and try to debug it in a smaller setting where I can isolate the problems or verify functionality more easily.

Comment: I have to go to sleep. Good night. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

try to modify your View to something like this:

```
class DatePopUpView: UIView {
     var uiView:UIView?
     override init()  {
         super.init()
         self.setup()
     }
     required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)  {
         super.init(coder: aDecoder)
         self.setup()
     }
     override init(frame: CGRect)   {
         super.init(frame: frame)
         self.setup()
     }
     setup() {
         self.uiView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("DatePopUpView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
         self.uiView.frame = self.bounds
         self.uiView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight
         self.addSubview(self.uiView)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**In storyboard**

- In storyboard create one UIViewController
- Set custom class as anotherViewController and Storyboard_ID as another_view_sid
- Create one new Cocoa Touch Class as anotherViewController and subclass of UIVIewController

**In viewController**

```
    let popvc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "another_view_sid") as! anotherViewController

    self.addChildViewController(popvc)

    popvc.view.frame = self.view.frame

    self.view.addSubview(popvc.view)

    popvc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

**In anotherViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        showAnimate()
    }
}

@IBAction func Close_popupView(_ sender: Any) {
    removeAnimate()
}

func showAnimate()
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    })
}

func removeAnimate()
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: {(finished : Bool) in
        if(finished)
        {
            self.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This is animation code works great. But, how to show as popup like alertview?

Answer (score 1):

Present the view as a modal segue

Check out this tutorial:

http://makeapppie.com/2014/08/30/the-swift-swift-tutorials-adding-modal-views-and-popovers/

You can use system provided segue transitions or make custom segue transitions to get really fancy effects.

Here's one approach to making custom transition animators:

```
//
//  BaseTransitionAnimator.swift
//

import UIKit

class BaseTransitionAnimator : NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    enum PresentationMode {
        case Presenting, Dismissing
    }
    var duration     : NSTimeInterval = 1.0
    var mode         : PresentationMode = .Presenting

    init(duration: NSTimeInterval, mode: PresentationMode) {
        self.duration = duration
        self.mode = mode
    }

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        // stub - must be overriden by inheritor
    }
```

---

```
//
//  ExpandingTransitionAnimator.swift
//

import UIKit

class ExpandingTransitionAnimator : BaseTransitionAnimator {

    enum ExpansionMode {
        case Basic, WithFadingImage
    }

    var image : UIImage? = nil

    override init(duration: NSTimeInterval, mode: PresentationMode) {
        super.init(duration: duration, mode: mode)
    }

    override func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        var fromVC             = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!
        var toVC               = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!
        var fromView           = fromVC.view
        var toView             = toVC.view
        var containerView      = transitionContext.containerView()
        var duration           = transitionDuration(transitionContext)
        var initialFrame       = transitionContext.initialFrameForViewController(fromVC)

        var imageView : UIImageView?
        if image != nil {
            imageView = UIImageView(image: image!.crop(CGPointMake(0, 0),  size: toView.frame.size))

        }
        if (mode == .Presenting) {  
                toView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05)
               var originalCenter = toView.center
                containerView.addSubview(toView)
                if imageView != nil {
                    imageView!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05);
                    containerView.addSubview(imageView!)
                }

                UIView.animateWithDuration(duration,
                    delay:0.0,
                    options:.CurveEaseInOut,
                    animations: {
                        if imageView != nil {
                            imageView!.alpha = 0.0
                            imageView!.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
                        }
                        toView.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
                        toView.center = originalCenter
                    },
                    completion: { _ in
                        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled())
                })
        } else { // dismissing
            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration,
                animations: {
                    fromView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05)
                    fromView.center = toView.center
                },
                completion: { _ in
                    fromView.removeFromSuperview()
                    transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled())
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it means instead of UIView i should create a UIViewcontroller and present it modally using suegue?

Comment: That code is For iPad only. In that it is mention. I am working on iPhone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73554/discussion-between-1s-and-0s-and-shruti).

Answer (score 0):

In the DatePopUpView looks like you are loading the nib file but not actually adding as subview to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version of Mili Shah's answer

```
let popvc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "another_view_sid") as! anotherViewController

self.addChild(popvc)
popvc.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popvc.view)
popvc.didMove(toParent: self)

@IBAction func Close_popupView(_ sender: Any) {
    removeAnimate()
}

func showAnimate() {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    })
}

func removeAnimate() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: {(finished : Bool) in
        if(finished)
        {
            self.willMove(toParent: nil)
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.removeFromParent()
        }
    })
}
```